# Error launching jupyter notebook with the errors from the command prompt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am new to jupyter notebook and I tried to launch it with the virtual environment using python 3.9. It did not work when I tried to open a file with extension .ipynb. It said "500 : Internal Server Error". I tried to follow some of the answers across the internet but it seems like none of the solutions worked. Here are my errors when I tried to open a file:

```
[E 15:17:15.635 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /notebooks/Documents/reseau_trait/Untitled.ipynb (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8889', method='GET', uri='/notebooks/Documents/reseau_trait/Untitled.ipynb', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1704, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 775, in run
        yielded = self.gen.send(value)
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 95, in get
        self.write(self.render_template('notebook.html',
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 516, in render_template
        return template.render(**ns)
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1291, in render
        self.environment.handle_exception()
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 925, in handle_exception
        raise rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source)
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 1, in top-level template code
        {% extends "page.html" %}
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/page.html", line 154, in top-level template code
        {% block header %}
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/templates/notebook.html", line 115, in block 'header'
        {% for exporter in get_frontend_exporters() %}
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/notebook/notebook/handlers.py", line 40, in get_frontend_exporters
        for name in get_export_names():
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 146, in get_export_names
        e = get_exporter(exporter_name)(config=config)
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/base.py", line 103, in get_exporter
        if getattr(exporter(config=config), 'enabled', True):
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 332, in __init__
        super().__init__(config=config, **kw)
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 118, in __init__
        self._init_preprocessors()
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 499, in _init_preprocessors
        conf = self._get_conf()
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/templateexporter.py", line 519, in _get_conf
        if conf_path.exists():
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1424, in exists
        self.stat()
      File "/home/adminlocal/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1232, in stat
        return self._accessor.stat(self)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/conf.json'
[E 15:17:15.640 NotebookApp] {
      "Host": "localhost:8889",
      "Connection": "keep-alive",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua": "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"97\", \"Chromium\";v=\"97\"",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile": "?0",
      "Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform": "\"Linux\"",
      "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36",
      "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
      "Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
      "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
      "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
      "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
      "Referer": "http://localhost:8889/tree/Documents/reseau_trait",
      "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
      "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8",
      "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|4458adb8|1f5328894bccc51d689db20587f6627f|1639398656; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1641912840|23:username-localhost-8888|44:MmQ5MzdjYTAyMDk4NGQwZDgzMWIyNDQ4NTM5MDVjOTA=|4ce346eb16c6e0b58eb0c8ded8da22d4276e2b77d3998a8a33457996b7fbbd18\"; username-localhost-8889=\"2|1:0|10:1641914229|23:username-localhost-8889|44:YzM1NWIyYjhiMzEzNDhmMTlkZGE3ZjEwNWFlMjEyNmI=|9ed369255c86f362e013818d6806bec13de9f1514ece473e76c833bcc8e117d4\""
    }
[E 15:17:15.640 NotebookApp] 500 GET /notebooks/Documents/reseau_trait/Untitled.ipynb (127.0.0.1) 87.020000ms referer=http://localhost:8889/tree/Documents/reseau_trait
```

Can you suggest the solutions due to the exact errors?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Have you tried opening "anconda prompt" as a admin & Thereby launching "jupyter notebook"?

Comment: I launched jupyter notebook in the virtual environment